# Difference between two methods of creating of 2d array

Tags: c++, memory-management

What is the difference between two arrays definitions? Are they realized different in memory?

```
 int var = 5;
 int (*p4)[2] = new int [var][2]; // first 2d array

 int** p5 = new int*[var];  // second 2d array
 for(int i = 0; i < var; ++i){
     p5[i] = new int[2];
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're very different. The first is really a single array; the second is actually `var+1` arrays, potentially scattered all over your RAM. `var` arrays hold the data, and one holds pointers to the `var` data arrays.

Comment: And don't use either one. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Better yet, [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html).

Comment: so, for the second case, how is for example cell p5[2][1] found? for the first case I guess it is something like *(p4 + 2*var + 1).

Comment: In the second case, `p5[2]` is a pointer to an array, which is followed, then the resulting array is indexed with 1.

Comment: so, for the second case, how is for example cell p5[2][1] found? for the first case I guess it is something like *(p4 + 2*var + 1) // that should be *((int * )p4 + 2*i + j), otherwise arithmetic for p4 will be wrong done

Comment: Regarding use of `std::vector` and boost: `std::vector` allocates ragged arrays, much the same as `int**`, and it adds a lot of functionality you do not want in this case. Don't use `std::vector` for such arrays. Regarding `boost`, I'm not a big fan (nor is my management. We can not use boost. Verboten.) Drag in a 7500 header file monster to solve a simple problem?

Comment: @DavidHammen: you mean learn a library that has so many useful features that if you use it thoroughly, it eventually decimates the size of your code and replaces your ad hoc solutions by tried and tested ones? ;)

Comment: @scdmb: To access `p4[i][j]`, that access is equivalent to `*(p4 +2*i + j)`. The outer dimension does not come into play. To access `p5[i][j]`, that access is equivalent to `*(*(p5+i)+j)`. The former goes through a pointer once; the latter, twice.

Comment: @DavidHammen: between ad hoc solutions and tried and tested ones? Maybe. I have found that Boost solves many tricky programming problems that I would have had to spend months on to get right.

Comment: @DavidHammen: statement: std::cout << p4[i][j] << ' ' << *(*(p4 + i) + j) << ' ' << *((int * )p4 + 2*i + j); shows the same thing, so I guess that two methods can be used for p4. However for int p4[var][2], p4+1 means, p4+1*2*sizeof(int) and for (int * )p4+1 it is p4+1*sizeof(int)

Comment: @scdmb: That is correct -- but it is not the best way to do things in your code. Much better is to prefer `p4[i][j]` in your code over pointer arithmetic. Let the compiler decide how to best implement that access in terms of pointer arithmetic. (And for a contiguous array, the compiler will always choose the single pointer method.)

Comment: @larsmans: You are assuming that a non-boost solution is ad hoc and untested. There are things called books and journals, and there are smaller packages than boost. It is a false dichotomy. You are ignoring that one big criticism against C++ is that it is a very bloated language. Adding a 7500 header package does not help with the bloat problem. There are downsides to using boost as well as upsides.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an ordinary, fully contiguous array, the second is also known as [jagged array or lliffe vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) and can e.g. be used to represent triangular structures.